# Problems with dropdown using CSS and jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to create a drop down menu using jQuery and CSS.
[Here is jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/v6TvC/)

But this doesn't seem to work well. Can anyone point what am I missing?

Comment: Can you describe what "doesn't seem to work well"?

Comment: @sergio: you can see that problem in the jsfiddle link. when i try to point my cursor to the submenu, the event onMouseOut is called. i cant understand why its happening..

Comment: I can access the Link .
But I can show you some jquery example :
http://designm.ag/resources/jquery-navigation-plugins/
Have a look at these example.

Comment: The last thing that I want to go to jsfiddle and try to figure out what "doesn't seem to work". If you do not care to properly ask question, why should I care to answer?

Comment: And, obviously, `onMouseOut` is called because mouse is moved out from that element.

Comment: but as you can see, mouse is not out from the id #userbox..

Comment: and when i use onMouseOver instead of onClick, its working properly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's working code, but it's a little bit more complicated than what you had:

```
var timer;

function openMenu() {
    $(this).addClass('open');
}

function keepOpen() {
    clearTimeout(timer);
}

function closeMenu() {
    $(this).removeClass('open');
    timer = setTimeout(function() {closeMenu(this);}, 50);
}

$('#userbox').hover(keepOpen, closeMenu);
$('#userbox').click(openMenu);
```

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/stulentsev/v6TvC/3/

Comment: thanks for this. its now working :) and i wonder why my code is working with onMouseOver instead of onClick !!

Comment: @JigneshManek: I'll give you a hint. `console.log` is your friend :-)

Answer (score 0):

Your current code is:

```
<div id="userbox" onClick="$(this).addClass('open');"      onMouseOut="$(this).removeClass('open');">
    <h3>Administrator</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The onClick is what I think is wrong, it should be onmouseover. When you change it to that:

```
<div id="userbox" onmouseover="$(this).addClass('open');" onMouseOut="$(this).removeClass('open');">
    <h3>Administrator</h3>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Settings</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Logout</a></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

The drop down menu works.

Hope this answer helps.

Answer (score 0):

just remove all the jquery from the code and add this in css

```
#userbox:hover ul{ display:block;}
```

**Demo :** http://jsfiddle.net/v6TvC/8/

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution I could come up with jQuery:

```
$('#userbox h3').click(function() {
    $('#userbox ul').show('100');
});

$('#userbox').bind('mouseleave', function() {
                   $('#userbox ul').hide('100');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

**[DEMO fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ndNnt/)**

```
$('#userbox').click(function(){
       $(this).addClass('open');
}).mouseleave(function(){
        $(this).removeClass('open');
});
```

---

**[DEMO fiddle 2](http://jsfiddle.net/ndNnt/1/)**

```
$('#userbox').bind('click mouseleave',function(ev){
    ev.type === 'click' ? $(this).addClass('open') : $(this).removeClass('open');
});
```